# Firefox for Android Addon-Sdk having more than one View in Home.panel

Tags: android, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm developing a **firefox for android addon**. I want to have a Home.panel for it. In the home panel, I'd like to have two diferent views. Firstly I would have a list of bookmarks and secondly a Grid with some options. **I HAVE A VERY GOOD REASON FOR DOING THIS WAY**.

I have tried so far the following:

```
const {Cu} = require("chrome");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Home.jsm");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/HomeProvider.jsm");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Task.jsm");

const PANEL_ID = "aurora_suite_pannel@ats.com";
const BOOKMARKS_DATASET_ID = "as_bookmarks_dataset@ats.com";
const MAINMENU_DATASET_ID = "as_mainmenu_dataset@ats.com";

function syncData2() {
  console.debug("Syncronizando ...");

  var bookmarks = [
    // An item
    { 
      url: "http://example.com/",
      title: "Example Web Site" ,
      description: "This is an example of a bookmark",
      image_url: "http://example.com/example.png"
    }
  ];

  var mainMenuItems = [
        {
            url: require("sdk/self").data.url("test.html"),
            title: "Grid item",
            description: "This is a Grid item",
            image_url: "http://example.com/test.png"
        }
  ];

  Task.spawn(function() {
    let bookmarksStorage = HomeProvider.getStorage(BOOKMARKS_DATASET_ID);
    let mainMenuStorage = HomeProvider.getStorage(MAINMENU_DATASET_ID);
    console.debug("Actual synching process. storage");

    // New way to replace items in Firefox 31+
    yield bookmarksStorage.save(bookmarks, { replace: true });
    yield mainMenuStorage.save(mainMenuItems, { replace: true });
  });
}

function optionsCallback() {
  return {
    title: "My Addon Panel",

    views: [{
      type: Home.panels.View.LIST,
      dataset: BOOKMARKS_DATASET_ID,
      // optional, only used if there's a filter applied after clicking on an item
      backImageUrl: "myBackIcon.png",
      // optional, defaults to BROWSER (can also specify INTENT to launch an intent)
      itemType: Home.panels.Item.ARTICLE,
      itemHandler: Home.panels.ItemHandler.BROWSER
    }, {
      type: Home.panels.View.GRID,
      dataset: MAINMENU_DATASET_ID,
      // optional, only used if there's a filter applied after clicking on an item
      backImageUrl: "myBackIcon.png",
      // optional, defaults to BROWSER (can also specify INTENT to launch an intent)
      itemType: Home.panels.Item.IMAGE,
      itemHandler: Home.panels.ItemHandler.BROWSER
    }],

    // optional, defaults to FRAME (only supported layout for v1)
    layout: Home.panels.Layout.FRAME,    
  }; 
}

exports.load = function(){
    console.debug("Loading addon Home Panel");

    try{
        Home.panels.uninstall(PANEL_ID);
        Home.panels.unregister(PANEL_ID);
    }catch(e){
        console.error("Ocurrio un error al desintalar el panel" + e);
        //console.exception(e);
    }

    Home.panels.register(PANEL_ID, optionsCallback);
    Home.panels.install(PANEL_ID);
    syncData2();
    //HomeProvider.requestSync(PANEL_ID, syncData2); // this doesn't work either
    Home.panels.update(PANEL_ID);
}

exports.unload = function(){
    console.debug("Unloading Addon Panel");

    Home.panels.uninstall(PANEL_ID);
    Home.panels.unregister(PANEL_ID);
}
```

the exported load function gets called when addon is loaded.

Acording to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Firefox_for_Android/API/Home.jsm/panels this is posible.

However, I can't make it work with two panels, only the first would load.

I haven't been able to find any information on this specific task so far. Thank you in advance.

The "TOP SITES" that comes with firefox does what I want. It shows a grid, then a list of choises.
[Firefox for Android TOP SITES panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfPlj.png)